# Terraria chest items disappearing

Tags: terraria-mobile

My cousin gave me some items and since my main character's inventory was full I made a new character so I didn't have to go through all my chests and put things away (playing on iOS, so there is no quick stack button ).

So I get the items and I get off my cousin's world and I go onto my world, which is stored in the cloud so I can access it from all my devices. 
I put the items in the chest and then log out. I then log back into that world with my main character and look in the chest to exchange the better items and whatnot but the items were gone.

Anyone know what happened? lots of things were lost :(